# Will specifying data type as MEDIUMTEXT, occupy more space even if data is less

Tags: mysql, sqldatatypes

I have a `MEDIUMTEXT` column type in mysql.

Doubt is -> Since all `TEXT` types are not stored withing the table, so specifying any column as `MEDIUMTEXT` would occupy `16 MB` or will it depend on the size data stored in it.

Answer (score 0):

MEDIUMTEXT will take one byte more than TEXT. But he will only use the size of the data.

See [Storage](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-requirements.html)